# Rails & UJS: serialize form to JSON and submit it

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, ujs

I'd like to serialize form params to JSON before the form is submitted. Is there any trickery in UJS that allows this?

Comment: What I did is just used `$.ajax` and set `type: 'script'`. Pls close this one as it's stupid, much like its author.

Comment: Where did you set type? Is that as a <form> attribute?